# How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I want to show the location of an address in Google Maps.

How do I get the latitude and longitude of an address using the Google Maps API?

Comment: I had the same issue Look at my solve here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19170557/2621050

Answer (score 149, accepted):

```
public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address;
    GeoPoint p1 = null;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new GeoPoint((double) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                (double) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

        return p1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

`strAddress` is a string containing the address. The `address` variable holds the converted addresses.

Comment: It throws the "java.io.IOException service not available"

Comment: You need the right permissions to be able to access the service. #
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: which android api version you are building application you need to have google api available i have build with google api 8. check that google api folder is there in your project.  and in your manifest file add uses library com.google.android.maps

Comment: i already gave those permission and include the library...i can get map view...it throws that IOException  at geocoder...

Comment: the logcat error was
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722): Service not Available
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:159)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at pack.sample.map.SampleMapApplication.onCreate(SampleMapApplication.java:36)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

Comment: 09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: 09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

Comment: 09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-02 16:32:22.861: ERROR/Exception(722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I had to add android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION as permission

Comment: You might check a way through deal with this problem  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816#c21 its pretty puch the same as geocoder

Comment: @Mr.Hyde which API version you are using ?

Comment: Check out the answer by @NayAneshGupte below, i don't think there is a `GeoPoint` class in the new libraries. Instead use `LatLng`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27834110/2968401

Comment: I call the method like "GeoPoint point= getLocationFromAddress("colombo,sri lanka");" but give null value. how to call it correctly

Comment: @LincolnWhite classes are changed with google maps api version V2 in place of GeoPoint new class is LatLang. you need google maps api in your project with key. and you just need to pass string address to this method to get lat,lang

Comment: the address can be empty, you should check for null and isEmpty...

Answer (score 93):

Ud_an's solution with updated API's

**Note**: [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) class is part of Google Play Services.

**Mandatory**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Update:** If you have target SDK 23 and above, make sure you take care of runtime permission for location.

```
public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context,String strAddress) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1 = null;

    try {
        // May throw an IOException
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Address location = address.get(0);
        p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() );

    } catch (IOException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return p1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, above solution was not working.

Comment: When instantiating the Geocoder you should pass context Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this); or new Geocoder(getApplicationContext) not getActivity() as stated in the answer.

Comment: @Quantumdroid above code is written in fragment. Otherwise you are absolutely correct. It's context.

Comment: Beautiful and clean solution. None of the answers mention that Geocoder uses synchronous access, as such it is highly recommended to put this in a background service to avoid blocking the UI.

Comment: Great Solution. IOException will be called when Invalid address/zipcode is entered. You can avoid that error with a simple  `if(address.size() <1){//show a Toast}else{//put rest of code here}`

Comment: Thanks @Nayanesh Gupte, its working perfectly for me

Comment: should check for runtime permisson on SDK version 23 above or below???

Comment: is this free or billable?

Answer (score 53):

If you want to place your address in google map then easy way to use following

```
Intent searchAddress = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+address));
startActivity(searchAddress);
```

OR

if you needed to get lat long from your address then use **Google Place Api** following

create a method that returns a **JSONObject** with the response of the **HTTP Call** like following

```
public static JSONObject getLocationInfo(String address) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {

        address = address.replaceAll(" ","%20");    

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


            response = client.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }
```

now pass that **JSONObject** to getLatLong() method like following

```
public static boolean getLatLong(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        try {

            longitute = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                .getDouble("lng");

            latitude = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                .getDouble("lat");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return false;

        }

        return true;
    }
```

I hope this helps to you nd others..!!
Thank you..!!

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesn't work with mobile connection of some mobile operators: the request always returns **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**. Those mobile operators use NAT overloading, assigning the same IP to many devices...

Comment: @UmbySlipKnot Can you explain more about OVER_QUERY_LIMIT? What is that? thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The following code will work for google apiv2:

```
public void convertAddress() {
    if (address != null && !address.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            List<Address> addressList = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
            if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                double lat = addressList.get(0).getLatitude();
                double lng = addressList.get(0).getLongitude();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // end catch
    } // end if
} // end convertAddress
```

Where address is the String (123 Testing Rd City State zip) you want to convert to LatLng.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to Kandha problem above :

> It throws the "java.io.IOException service not available" 
>   i already gave those permission and include the library...i can get map view...it throws that IOException at geocoder...

I just added a catch IOException after the try and it solved the problem

```
    catch(IOException ioEx){
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void goToLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {
    //Create coder with Activity context - this
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address;

    try {
        //Get latLng from String
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);

        //check for null
        if (address != null) {

            //Lets take first possibility from the all possibilities.
            try {
                Address location = address.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                //Animate and Zoon on that map location
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException er) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 yourButton.setOnClickListener {
            AppUtil.hideSoftKeyboard(this)
            if (yourEdittext.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                var location: LatLng? = null
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                    val coder = Geocoder(this@WeatherMapActivity)
                    coder.getFromLocationName(yourEdittext.text.toString(), 5,object :Geocoder.GeocodeListener{
                        override fun onGeocode(addresses: MutableList<Address>) {
                            addresses.forEach {
                                //do your work android 13
                                Log.d("locationFRR", "onGeocode: ${it.latitude}")
                                Log.d("locationFRR", "onGeocode: ${it.longitude}")
                                location = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)
                            }

                            location?.let {
                                Log.d("locationFRR", "onCreate: ${it.latitude}")
                                Log.d("locationFRR", "onCreate: ${it.longitude}")
                                getWeather(it.latitude.toString(), it.longitude.toString())
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onError(errorMessage: String?) {
                            super.onError(errorMessage)
                            Log.d("locationFRR", "onError: $errorMessage")
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@WeatherMapActivity,
                                "City not found",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    })

                } else {
                    //less than Android 13
                    //using Coroutine to avoid ANRs

                    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        location =
                            getLocationFromAddress(yourEdittext.text.toString())
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            location?.let {
                                Log.d("locationFRR", "onCreate: ${it.latitude}")
                                Log.d("locationFRR", "onCreate: ${it.longitude}")
                                getWeather(it.latitude.toString(), it.longitude.toString())
                            } ?: run {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    this@WeatherMapActivity,
                                    "City not found",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }

 private fun getLocationFromAddress(strAddress: String): LatLng? {
        val coder = Geocoder(this)
        var p1: LatLng? = null
        try {
            val address: MutableList<Address>? = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5)

            address?.let {
                if (it.size > 0) {


                    address[0].let { add ->
                        p1 = LatLng(
                            (add.latitude),
                            (add.longitude)
                        )
                    }

                }

                Log.d("locationFRR", "getLocationFromAddress: $p1")
            }

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.d("locationFRR", "getLocationFromAddress: ${e.message}")
        }
        return p1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = coder.getFromLocationName(address, 5);
            if (addresses == null) {
            }
            Address location = addresses.get(0);
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            Log.i("Lat",""+lat);
            Log.i("Lng",""+lng);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,12));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: That null check is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
public LatLang getLatLangFromAddress(String strAddress){
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> address;
    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
        if (address == null) {
                return new LatLang(-10000, -10000);
            }
            Address location = address.get(0);
            return new LatLang(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new LatLang(-10000, -10000);
        }
    }
```

`LatLang` is a pojo class in this case.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` permission is not required.

Answer (score -1):

I know I am too late for the contribution of 10 years old question, in the year 2021. The following code is fully complete working code.

code for activity_main.xml:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter Address"
    android:id="@+id/addressTV"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addressET"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/addressTV"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW Washington DC 20502" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Lat/Long"
    android:id="@+id/addressButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addressTV"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/addressTV"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/latLongTV"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/addressTV" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml
Give following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button addressButton;
TextView addressTV;
TextView latLongTV;
EditText addressET;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addressET = findViewById(R.id.addressET);
    addressTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressTV);
    latLongTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latLongTV);

    addressButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addressButton);
    addressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            String address = addressET.getText().toString();

            GeocodingLocation locationAddress = new GeocodingLocation();
            locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(address,
                    getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());


           
        }
    });

}

private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        String address;
        switch (message.what) {
            case 1:
                Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                address = bundle.getString("address");
                break;
            default:
                address = null;
        }
        latLongTV.setText(address);
    }
}
```

}

GeocodingLocation.java

```
public class GeocodingLocation {



public static void getAddressFromLocation(String locationAddress, Context context,  Handler handler) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            String result = null;

            try {
                List addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress,1);
                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0){
                    Address address = (Address) addressList.get(0);
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    stringBuilder.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n");
                    stringBuilder.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n");
                    result = stringBuilder.toString();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.setTarget(handler);
                if (result != null){
                    message.what = 1;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    result = "Address   :   "+locationAddress+
                            "\n\n\nLatitude and longitude\n"+result;
                    bundle.putString("address",result);
                    message.setData(bundle);
                }
                message.sendToTarget();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

}