# Android Geocode error:java.io.IOException on emulator, SDK 2.3

Tags: android

I want to use GeoCoder class in my app. I followed the steps as in this question

[How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-latitude-and-longitude-using-address/3574792#3574792)

but received the error: `java.io.IOException` in the emulator, despite I included the required permissions.

I'm using Google APIs 2.3.1 API level 9.

Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it. It's a bug in the emulator of sdk 9. I switched the target to sdk 2.1 and it worked.