# "Google Map" how can we get Lattitude and Longitude by passing the Address

Tags: android, google-maps, location

In Google Maps how can we get Latitude and Longitude by passing the Address?

and what is the Address format need to be mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-latitude-and-longitude-using-address/3574792#3574792). Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

To find latitude and longitude from address string .....

1. Make object of `Geocoder`
2. Call `getFromLocationName()` pass the address (place name) string as argument also  maximum number of results you want for that place name

Here is demo ...

```
       Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(LocationMap.this);

       List<Address> geocodeResults = coder.getFromLocationName(placeName, 10);

       Iterator<Address> locations = geocodeResults.iterator();

       while (locations.hasNext()) {

           Address loc = locations.next();

           _lattitude_ = loc.getLatitude() ;
           _longidude_ = loc.getLongitude();

       }
```

And there are no specific address format required.

For example you can try any city name, country name, hotel name, area name, road name, well known place name ( Try "Eiffel tower") ... anything (from many things).