# Obtaining Coordinates from "Share this place" in Google Maps

Tags: android

When viewing the details of any location in Google Maps, there's an option for "Share this place". I have successfully added myself to the list of receivers by adding this intent-filter to my application in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

The extras passed along with this bundle are Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT and Intent.EXTRA_TEXT. I retrieved these extras in my activity using:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT contains a string with the title of the location.
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT contains a string with a detailed address of the location and a mobile maps URL.

Is it at all possible to retrieve the GPS co-ordinates (latitude and longitude) of the location from the "Share this place" action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use geocoder to obtain the location from the address:

[How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-latitude-and-longitude-using-address/3574792#3574792)

Comment: I was hoping for a more direct approach without having to look up the address, but this does the trick. Thanks!

Note: I had to strip the URL from the text in order for the Geocoder to locate the address correctly.