# Android Geocoder is not available?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I am using this method to get location by address and I am using android 4.2.2 device.

```
addresses = g.getFromLocationName(addressString, 1);
```

When I tried to get the address location first time it's give me the actual result. But after few days it says that `Geocoder` service is not available. 
My question is I used same device, same api key and its worked but now it is not working. Why? 
How can solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This a problem from Google itself.

You can solve the problem if you restart your device. But thats not the best solution for a user.

You can make a workaround like this:

```
public void getCityName(){ 
    if (running)
        return;

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
        String streetName = null;
        //String cityName = null;

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            running = true;
        };

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
            if (Geocoder.isPresent()){ //if geocoder network is not crashed
                try{
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(locationAll.getLatitude(), locationAll.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if (addresses.size() > 0){
                        cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    }
                    for (Address address : addresses) {
                        System.out.println("my location .."+address.getAddressLine(0));
                        streetName = address.getAddressLine(0);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ignored){
                    // after a while, Geocoder start to throw "Service not available" exception. really weird since it was working before (same device, same Android version etc..
                }
            }

            if (cityName != null){ // Geocoder succeed

                return cityName;
            }
            else // Geocoder failed
            {
                return fetchCityNameUsingGoogleMap();
            }
        }

        // Geocoder failed :-(
        // My B Plan : Google Map
        private String fetchCityNameUsingGoogleMap()
        {
            String googleMapUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + locationAll.getLatitude() + ","
                    + locationAll.getLongitude() + "&sensor=false&language=fr";


            try
            {
                JSONObject googleMapResponse = new JSONObject(ANDROID_HTTP_CLIENT.execute(new HttpGet(googleMapUrl),
                        new BasicResponseHandler()));

                // many nested loops.. not great -> use expression instead
                // loop among all results
                JSONArray results = (JSONArray) googleMapResponse.get("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++)
                {
                    // loop among all addresses within this result
                    JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (result.has("address_components"))
                    {
                        JSONArray addressComponents = result.getJSONArray("address_components");
                        // loop among all address component to find a 'locality' or 'sublocality'
                        for (int j = 0; j < addressComponents.length(); j++)
                        {
                            JSONObject addressComponent = addressComponents.getJSONObject(j);
                            if (result.has("types"))
                            {
                                JSONArray types = addressComponent.getJSONArray("types");

                                // search for locality and sublocality
                                cityName = null;

                                for (int k = 0; k < types.length(); k++)
                                {
                                    if ("locality".equals(types.getString(k)) && cityName == null)
                                    {
                                        if (addressComponent.has("long_name"))
                                        {
                                            cityName = addressComponent.getString("long_name");
                                        }
                                        else if (addressComponent.has("short_name"))
                                        {
                                            cityName = addressComponent.getString("short_name");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if ("sublocality".equals(types.getString(k)))
                                    {
                                        if (addressComponent.has("long_name"))
                                        {
                                            cityName = addressComponent.getString("long_name");
                                        }
                                        else if (addressComponent.has("short_name"))
                                        {
                                            cityName = addressComponent.getString("short_name");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (cityName != null)
                                {

                                    return cityName;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ignored)
            {
                ignored.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String cityName)
        {
            running = false;
            if (cityName != null)
            {
                // Do something with cityName
                Log.i("GeocoderHelper", cityName);
            }
        };     
}.execute();

}
```

I just want the cityname, you can get any further informations.

If `Geocoder` dont succed it gets the information through `HTTP`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you over the max. QUERY_LIMIT? Do you see any logs to that effect when it's stopped working? Or any logs at all?

Answer (score 0):

**Please build the application using api level with google api (eg. Google APIs (google Inc.) Api level 14)**

I faced the same issue while trying to call geoCoder.getFromLocationName(addressString, 1);
To work we need to restart the device. but it is not the exact solution. so pls try the above solution in my case its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Check my Answser for [How to get the latitude and longitude from city name in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008108/how-to-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-city-name-in-android/10008390#10008390)

My suggestion is to use Google GeoCoding REST API , not Geocoder.

Because I once used it in my country,China,I have a error below:

```
"java.io.IOException: Service not Available"
```

after search , It`s seems that

```
"The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android              framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation    exists."
```

So I turn to Google GeoCoding REST API , It`s easy , just request like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NewYork&sensor=false
```

You will get a json that has geo location in it.
And You can also get Address from locaiton through it:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false
```

If you can read Chinese , I have a blog about this,check this out:
    http://wangchao.de/android%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8google-geocoding-api%E6%9B%BF%E4%BB%A3geocoder-%E8%A7%A3%E5%86%B3%E5%9C%B0%E5%9D%80%E8%AF%AD%E8%A8%80%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98