# Get latitude and longitude from a specific city android

Tags: android

How could I select latitude and longitude for a specific city ? Actually, how could I get the city itself with its longitude and latitude.

For example, I make an EditText where I do tap "Rome". How could I get the Rome itself with its latitude and longitude ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have basically asked 2 questions

**1. Getting lat long from city name**

Try this URL:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=mumbai&sensor=false

The above URL returns the data in JSON format which then you can parse to get the corresponding lat long values.

**2. Getting city name from lat long**

Try this URL:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838

Simply replace the lat long values in this URL.
You can parse the JSON received to get the city name from this.