# How to get latitude & longitude from address on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address)

I want to get latitude and longitude of particular address . How can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void getFromLocation(String address)
    {
          double latitude= 0.0, longtitude= 0.0;

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());    
        try 
        {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(address , 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
            {            
                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

                latitude=p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
                longtitude=p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;


                }
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no GeoPoint Class here .?

Comment: this is old answer. You need to add google map apis in build.gradle

Comment: or you can directly get latitude and longitude from Address object.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you (loop through) all the matches of the address string.
If you just desire the first match, make sure address.size() is great than 0, then take `address.get(0);`

In my usage, I get all matches, and show them as options. The user then clicks one, and it selects that GPS location.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());  
List<Address> addresses;
try {
   addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName("Example StreeT, UK, DNFE", 20);

   for(int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) { // MULTIPLE MATCHES

     Address addr = addresses.get(i);

     double latitude = addr.getLatitude();
     double longitude = addr.getLongitude(); // DO SOMETHING WITH VALUES

   }

}
```

Comment: thank u for quick response.. i'll try this

Answer (score 2):

You can get from the below code,

```
private void GetLatitudeAndLongitude() {
    geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(txtLocation.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase(), 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            homeInfoModel.setLalitude(String.valueOf(addresses.get(0).getLatitude()));
            homeInfoModel.setLongitude(String.valueOf(addresses.get(0).getLongitude()));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```