# How to get latitude and longitude by address location in Android

Tags: android, gps

I am developing Android app in which I am taking destination in edit-text and I want latitude and longitude of that entered location.

example: I have typed in edit-text pune now I want its latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

From here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3574792/2065418

```
   Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                          (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

         return p1;
    }
```

`strAddress` is a string containing the address. The `address` variable holds the converted addresses.