# Trying to get LatLng from an address or location in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

Ok next problem.

I am trying to take an imputed address or location and output a LatLng for storage.
This is what I have so far based on [How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address:), third answer down.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;

public class Mapping extends Fragment
{


    public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String _address) {

        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
        List<Address> address;
        LatLng p1 = null;

        try {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(_address, 1);
            if (address == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Address location = address.get(0);
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();

            p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() );

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return p1;
```

I try to call it in another class like this.

```
 make.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                //String _name = (String) txtName.getText().toString();
                //String _address = (String) txtAddress.getText().toString();
                String _name = "Some Name"; //Just to pass some information
                String _address = "New York";
                contact.setName(_name);
                contact.setAddress(_address);

                // Should populate lladdress with a LatLng
                LatLng lladdress = mapping.getLocationFromAddress(_address);
                contact.setLatLng(lladdress);
           }
});
```

All the code up to `// Should populate lladdress with a LatLng` works but if I add this part in my app stops working. I have used Toast in the past to test the code but I don't know how to test this and I try and debug and don't see anything useful. Any ideas of what is wrong with my code?

Update:
Thanks @bjiang for your code. I decided to change it so output a double[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) and return it so I can store it in a database or use it how I need later.

```js
public class Mapping extends Fragment
{
 
 //String[] happy = new String[2];
 
 protected double[] getLatLng(Context context, String address/*, boolean setDestination*/) {
        String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                + address + "&sensor=false";
        
  Message.message(context , ""+uri);

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

            int byteData;
            while ((byteData = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) byteData);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        double[] _latlng = new double[2];

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            _latlng[1] = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                    .getDouble("lng");
            _latlng[0] = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                    .getDouble("lat");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
  return _latlng;
```

It is still failing and from what I am reading from the exception it is throwing "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) post I need to run it as an AsyncTask but I am not sure if this is true or how to do it. does my code look right and does anyone have any other ideas?

Here is some of the log:

03-15 12:30:05.803: E/AndroidRuntime(17863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-15 12:30:05.803: E/AndroidRuntime(17863): Process: edu.ecpi.myappv3, PID: 17863

03-15 12:30:05.803: E/AndroidRuntime(17863): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

03-15 12:30:05.803: E/AndroidRuntime(17863):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)

03-15 12:30:05.803: E/AndroidRuntime(17863):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)

03-15 12:30:05.803: E/AndroidRuntime(17863):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)

03-15 12:30:05.803: E/AndroidRuntime(17863):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)

03-15 12:30:05.803: E/AndroidRuntime(17863):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:172)

03-15 12:30:05.803: E/AndroidRuntime(17863):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167)

Comment: one issue, in your method getLocationFromAddress, you return a null if the the method coder.getFromLocationName returns a null but in your method where call the method you are not checking to see if lladdress is null, add if(lladdress==null) after it returns from the mapping.getLocationFromAddress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used following method to get the `LatLng` form an address:

```
protected void getLatLng(String address) {
        String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                + address + "&sensor=false";

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

            int byteData;
            while ((byteData = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) byteData);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        double lat = 0.0, lng = 0.0;

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            lng = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                    .getDouble("lng");
            lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                    .getDouble("lat");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

You need put it into `AsyncTask` to `doInBackground` to fetch the data form Internet.

For whole project source code, please refer to my Github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android). This demonstrate `get LatLng form the address` and also can `set a marker to there`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bjiang I updated my post please look and see if you can help.

Comment: please check whole source code on my github will help you deal with asynctask

Comment: Yes thank you I did and the answers are there. I am just having trouble implementing it the way I need it. I fallow the code through the debug and it looks like it is getting the lat and lng like it should but then fails. I think it is saying something about trying to read a null array. I will take a little time away from the code then go at it again with fresh eyes. Thanks for your help.