# When find the latitude and longitude from address, how to give the address?

Tags: android, google-maps

I follow this question ([How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address)) and try to get the latitude and longitude of an address. I call the method like this "GeoPoint point=getLocationFromAddress("colombo,sri lanka");" . but give null value. how to call method correctly??

```
public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress){

Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;
GeoPoint p1 = null;

try {
address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
if (address==null) {
   return null;
}
Address location=address.get(0);
location.getLatitude();
location.getLongitude();

p1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                  (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

return p1;
}
}
```

Comment: From the API doc, " The results are a best guess and are not guaranteed to be meaningful or correct.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should use google place autocomplete/place picker api's.
Select the place and thereafter you can get Latitude and Longitude.
Check this out:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Comment: Be aware that this method uses Google API client which may not be available for Kindle

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(ReserveTimer.this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lati), Double.parseDouble(longi), 1);  

                                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                                    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
 System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));


System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getPostalCode());

                                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method that take a Location object that contain latitud and longitud coordinates and Log the location to the LogCat console:

```
public void setLocation(Location loc) {
  //Get Human readable address from latitud and longitud coordinates 
  if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
    try {
      Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
      List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
      if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    Address address = list.get(0);
    Log.d(CLASS_TAG, "Mi direcci—n es: \n" + address.getAddressLine(0));
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```