# Notification regarding your location in Android app

Tags: android, geolocation

I want to create an android app which asks user for a location input and runs in the background. Whenever user is within 1km radius of the location the app will display a notification “Within 1 km of xyz location”..

If nor the same,can anyone suggest me similar solution.

Thank you.

Comment: first atleast try something yourself and if you have any problems then ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

Step : 1 Firstly  get latitude and longitude 
this Url help you.

[How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address)

Step :2 Save the latitude and longitude

Step :3 By the onLocationChanged method you can get the required distance, after that you can generate notification.

May be this help you.