# Android Google Map Markers get latitude and longitude from address in Firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to get latitude and longitude from address. I read that I can use Geocoder to convert address to Lat and Long.

However, I'm not sure how to implement this as I'm manually storing the address, lat and long of the location and retrieving it from firebase. I'm adding the markers on the map through the coords. But what I want is getting the coordinates from the address instead of the manually putting in the coords. Do I add the `Geocoder` function under the part where I retrieve the address? How do I do that?

This is the example I read : 
[How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address)

**LocationRemitActivity.java**

```
 public class LocationRemitActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
        public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "";
        private static final String TAG = "tag";
        private ClusterManager<StoreLatLng> mClusterManager;
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_remit_location);

            ButterKnife.bind(this);

            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            // Marker Cluster
            setUpClusterer();
            mMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(false);
        }

        private void setUpClusterer() {
            // Position the map.
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(1.304414, 103.834006), 17));

            // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
            // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
            mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, mMap);

            // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
            // manager.
            mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager); //added
            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());

            // Listener for Info-Window Click , Parse data to next activity.
            mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<StoreLatLng>() {
                @Override
                public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(StoreLatLng myItem) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LocationRemitActivity.this, SelectedStoreDetail.class);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, myItem.getTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("snippet", myItem.getSnippet());
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putParcelable("latlng", myItem.getPosition());
                    intent.putExtra("bundle", args);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // Setting Cluster On Click ~> Zoom in 1 level .
            mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<StoreLatLng>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onClusterClick(final Cluster<StoreLatLng> cluster) {
    //                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cluster.getPosition(), (float) Math.floor(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom + 1)), 300, null);
                    BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialogFragment.getInstance();
                    bottomSheetDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Custom Bottom Sheet");
                    return true;
                }
            });

            // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.
            addItems();
        }


        //

        private void addItems() {

            // Firebase Setup to Retrieve Data
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if (postSnapshot.hasChild("Info")) {

                            // Get Data from Firebase (Name , Address , Lat , Lng)
                            String locationName = String.valueOf(postSnapshot.child("Info").child("Name").getValue());
                            String locationAddress = String.valueOf(postSnapshot.child("Info").child("Address").getValue());
                            double locationlat = (double) postSnapshot.child("Info").child("lat").getValue();
                            double locationlng = (double) postSnapshot.child("Info").child("lng").getValue();

                            if (locationName != null && locationAddress != null) {
                                // Create Marker inside MyItem + add markers to mClusterManager
                                StoreLatLng item = new StoreLatLng(locationlat, locationlng, locationName, locationAddress);
                                mClusterManager.addItem(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // Failed to read value
                    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you found your answer?

Comment: @RounakLahoti haha no, I have no idea on how to implement geocoder onto my codes.