# How to get Lat Long using Adress AND Zip Code Android

Tags: android, google-maps

There was a question years ago, how to get lat long coordinates using only the adress ( here is the link to the question: [How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address) )

I understand the accepted answer there, but my problem is, for example, in Germany you have no unique adresses, so if I use only adresses to get lat and long coordinates, I may get wrong lat long coordinates. Like, there is one adress called "Hauptstrasse" which is in Berlin and in Frankfurt. So I will get wrong coordinates.

Is there any way to use Adress AND Zip code to get the right lat long coordinates ?

This code for example only uses adresses:

```
public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress){

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address;
    GeoPoint p1 = null;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
        if (address==null) {
           return null;
        }
        Address location=address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new GeoPoint((double) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                          (double) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

        return p1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

This is how I solved this problem.

I have a txt file that contains adresses, zip codes and city names.

To keep your example for Germany:  Hauptstrasse 123, 10978, Germany (this will be somewhere in Berlin)

Then, I put this txt file into assets folder and used a `BufferedReader` and created an Array.

```
    public void readFile(){

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("YOURFILE")));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String splittedLine [] = line.split(",");
                int numberofElements =2;
                String[] onlyAdressandZip = Arrays.copyOf(splittedLine, numberofElements);
 } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As you can see, I did not use the name of the country (Germany) that's why I used `Arrays.copyOf`

Hauptstrasse 123, 10978 , Germany has a length of 3 but we only need Hauptstrasse 123 and 10978 that explains `int numberofElements =2`

That's it and then you can give `onlyAdressandZip[0]` and `onlyAdressandZip[1]` as input for the [GeoCoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) to get the right lat and long coordinates.