# API to get the longitude & latitude based on given name

Tags: android, api, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I have an android app that have an Edit text in which users can enter a city name and the app must get the longitude and latitude for use in calling another API.

How can I implement this type of thing?

I searched for and found that google geocoding API should help me ,but I must also implement google maps API, I don't know if this right.

However, my app must not have a map at all.

If this is right, is there any other api that I can give it the city name and return the longitude and latitude of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement Google Maps. You can use Google Place Autocomplete: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete.

With this, you will have a search bar and when you type, it will fetch the places and give you latitude / longitude and much more.

You can easily add Google Places to build.gradle: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'`

Comment: Thank you so much.
This solve my problem.
That is so much effective than normal Edit text.